# Can a global class instance be visible to COM in C#?

Tags: c#, vba, static, com

Can I create a global instance of a class in C# that is visible over COM?

Reason: I'm porting a VBA class library to C# to use over COM, and I want to provide some form of non-default constructors.

But, COM doesn't allow non-default constructors, nor can it directly access static class methods, which I would have used for non-default constructors.  It needs an instance of the class to call the methods.  My last idea for a workaround is to just provide a global instance of that class.  This is actually what I did with the original VBA code by setting `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True`.

But, global variables in C# are always contained in a static class that can't be accessed over COM.

#### EDIT

So in VBA a sample class using this strategy is (raw code of Box.cls)

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Box"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False ' prohibit `new Box` from outside project
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True  ' creates object `Box`
Attribute VB_Exposed = True

Option Explicit

Private pStr As String
' "Constructor"
Public Function Make(ByVal x as String)
    Dim result As New Box
    result.Inject x
    Set Make = result
End Function

Friend Sub Inject(ByVal x As String)
    pStr = x
End Sub
Public Property Get Inside() As String
    Inside = pStr
End Property
```

Then the usage would be like

```
Dim b As Box ' Box as a type
Set b = Box.Make("example") ' Box as a global instance
debug.assert b.Inside = "example" 
debug.assert Box.Inside = "" ' side affect is you can do this.
```

The C# code I am looking at is like

```
public class Box {
    private string _str;
    public Box() {} // _str still empty
    public Box(string str) { _str = str; } // Can't call from COM
    public static Box nogood(string str)   // Can't call from COM
    {
        return new Box(str); 
    } 
    public Box make(string str)  //.Can call but I need an instance of Box first.
    {
         return new Box(str);
    }
   //...
}
```

I would like to use the C# class from VBA as I already and would like to avoid doing this

```
Dim boxMaker as New Box

Dim b As Box
Set b = boxMaker.make("hello")
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample or example of the code you are working with and how you want to access it?

Comment: What you are looking for is not possible.  COM Automation has the [appobject] attribute to auto-construct objects but it is not supported in .NET.  Just untangle it, you need to write a separate BoxFactory class.  Having to use the New keyword to create the factory is, well, normal.

Comment: @HansPassant would C++ or some other language support the appobject attribute?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, but an easy way to emulate a global instance is to use a global function to return a static instance:

```vb
Public Function Box() As Box
  Static instance As New Box
  Set Box = instance
End Function

Sub Usage()
  Dim b As Box
  Set b = Box.make("hello")
End Sub
```